# Set key from a class variable in google app engine

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

I have this class and i want to use the phone as key. The key is fron a form input 
task.phone = self.request.get('phone'). I searched for answer but the only that i found it was from inside the code (like task=(phone = 5555) ).

```
class task(db.Model):
    name = db.StringProperty()
    lanme = db.StringProperty()
    phone = db.StringProperty()
    adress = db.StringProperty()
    visits = db.IntegerProperty()
```

Answer (score 1):

a simple solution would be:

```
task = task(key_name=adress)
```

A more advanced one would be:

```
class task(db.Model):
    ...
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        kwargs['key_name'] = kwargs['adress']
        db.Model.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
```

But what you need to keep in mind is that appengine doesn't use a particular field as key, there will always be a key and that may or may not match a particular field. If they are the same, is a "coincidence". As a general suggestion, leave the key as it is. There are some issues you may not be considering such as uniqueness of keys and overriding them.

Couple of side notes:

1. Class name should be Task not task
2. It's address not adress

Comment: about your notes, that was from fast typing. I want this key, because I want to use get_or_insert(), for examble if I input a phone (ie) 555 and this is already stored, I dont want to add him again but to update the visits to (ie) +2 +3 whatever..
Here is my question about this http://stackoverflow.com/q/7441456/948322 . But thank you!

Comment: Please don't override `__init__` on a Model. It's far too easy to get wrong, and changes to the db API may break it. In fact, I'm pretty sure your example is broken and will fail when the API reconstitutes instances from the datastore.

Comment: @Nick Johnson Yes i know, but really i dont know any other way to do this this http://stackoverflow.com/q/7441456/948322 problem.  If you can, take a look.

Comment: @Iwannhs Your problem has nothing to do with overriding `__init__` specifically - just pass in the key name using the `key_name` argument as fceruti suggests at the start.